# Neo4J Louvain algorithm returning different results with different sorting method

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to run the Louvain method of community detection on my database to group some of my nodes into clusters. However, I kept getting different results even just by trying to sort my results.

This is the result I get when I run the Louvain algorithm with no 'order by':

[image]

However, when I try to order my results by communityId, the communityId that was assigned to most of the nodes changes:

[image]

And when I try to order by nodeId instead, the communityId that was assigned changes again:

[image]

Can I get some help in understanding this please? I do understand that for Louvain algorithm, the initial communities assigned may be random at first, and hence, the end results could be different. However, I'm only introducing / changing the sorting order of the results here, not doing anything substantial to change the algorithm or the hyperparameter itself. So I'm really puzzled at how I could get different results in different runs.

I'm using Neo4J ver 4.3.1, with GDS ver 1.6.4, if that matters. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Louvain algorithm is non-deterministic, and therefore some nodes are sometimes grouped together in communities and sometimes not. Despite the non-determinism, you should get more or less similar results on every run.
Do not try to determine the results based on the community ids, as they have hold no information, like you mentioned, the initial communities are assigned random at first. If you want to determine how similar results are between different runs, try to compare communities and their members and disregard actual community ids.